# how to set up progress bar in hybrid app with WebView in Xamarin ios

Tags: webview, xamarin.ios, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm trying to get an ios version of a hybrid webview app to display some progress controls for when I do some lengthier operations, but don't know how to set it up.  In my Android version, I basically create the progress controls in the Main.axml initially hidden and then just unhide them when I need them:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/ProgressSpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ProgressText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I do the equivalent in ios?  Here is the storyboard.main that the project wizard set up for me with a WebView app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="6211" systemVersion="14A298i" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="6204"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customModuleProvider="" customClass="WebViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="3"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="4"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <webView key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="2BG-WL-JVn">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    </webView>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="WebView" destination="2BG-WL-JVn" id="name-outlet-2BG-WL-JVn"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

If I try to use the storyboard editor and drop a progress bar, it just replaces the WebView.

I also tried doing it programmatically in the WebViewController.  First the set up:

```
public static UIWebView webView;
public static UIActivityIndicatorView progressSpinner;
public static UIProgressView progressBar;
public static UILabel progressText;
// ...

// Get web view from storyboard backing code.
webView = WebView;

// Set up activity indicator.
progressSpinner = new UIActivityIndicatorView(UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray);
CGRect bounds = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
nfloat centerX = bounds.Width / 2;
nfloat centerY = bounds.Height / 2;
progressSpinner.Frame = new CGRect(
    centerX - (progressSpinner.Frame.Width / 2),
    bounds.Top,
    progressSpinner.Frame.Width,
    progressSpinner.Frame.Height);
progressSpinner.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;
progressSpinner.Hidden = false;
View.InsertSubviewAbove(progressSpinner, webView);

// Set up progress bar.
progressBar = new UIProgressView(UIProgressViewStyle.Bar);
progressBar.Frame = new CGRect(
    bounds.Left,
    progressSpinner.Frame.Bottom,
    bounds.Width,
    progressSpinner.Frame.Height);
progressBar.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;
progressBar.Hidden = false;
View.InsertSubviewAbove(progressBar, webView);

// Set up progress text message.
progressText = new UILabel();
progressText.Frame = new CGRect(
    bounds.Left,
    progressBar.Frame.Bottom,
    bounds.Width,
    progressText.Frame.Height);
progressText.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;
progressText.Hidden = false;
View.InsertSubviewAbove(progressText, webView);
```

Then using it:

```
public override void ProgressOperation(ProgressMode mode, int value, string message)
{
    UIActivityIndicatorView progressSpinner = WebViewController.progressSpinner;
    UIProgressView progressBar = WebViewController.progressBar;
    UILabel progressText = WebViewController.progressText;

    if (progressBar == null)
        return;

    switch (mode)
    {
        case ProgressMode.Start:
            InProgress = true;
            ProgressMax = value;
            if (value <= 0)
                ProgressMax = 1.0f;
            progressBar.Hidden = false;
            progressBar.Progress = 0.0f;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            {
                progressText.Text = message;
                progressText.Hidden = false;
                HaveMessage = true;
            }
            break;
        case ProgressMode.Update:
            if (InProgress)
            {
                progressBar.Progress = value / ProgressMax;
                if (HaveMessage)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
                        progressText.Text = message;
                }
            }
            break;
        case ProgressMode.Stop:
            progressBar.Hidden = true;
            progressText.Text = String.Empty;
            progressText.Hidden = true;
            InProgress = false;
            HaveMessage = false;
            break;
        case ProgressMode.Hide:
            progressSpinner.StopAnimating();
            progressSpinner.Hidden = true;
            break;
        case ProgressMode.Show:
            progressSpinner.Hidden = false;
            progressSpinner.StartAnimating();
            break;
        case ProgressMode.DelayedShow:
            if (InDelayedProgress)
            {
                progressSpinner.Hidden = false;
                progressSpinner.StartAnimating();
            }
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception("ProgressOperation: Need mode support for: " + mode.ToString());
    }
}
```

Although the code showing and hiding the spinner or other controls is executed, the controls are never visible. If anyone can help out this novice totally lost in the platform specific stuff, I'd appreciate it.  Thanks.

-John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I finally ended up doing was to go through the first couple parts of one of Apple's xcode interface builder tutorials (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/).  From that I was able to deduce that I needed to start with a View with an embedded vertical stack view with embedded activity indicator, progress bar, label, and web view controls, setting up the constraints appropriately, and even experimenting with outlets and a little Swift code.

I then tried to do the same thing with the Xamarin interface builder, even following one of their tutorials, but I couldn't make sense of the constraint mechanism to do what I did in xcode, so I gave up and just copied the xcode storyboard source.  I had to hack it a bit to get it to work.  I had to reuse some of the same attributes from the Xamarin version, delete the outlets, and redo the outlets with Xamarin's interface builder.

I'm surprised that no one could have taken a couple minutes to give me a hint to change from using a web view as the main view to a view->stack view->spinner+bar+label+web hierarchy.  But I guess the few hours learning a bit about xcode was probably time well-spent and kind of fun too.  The xcode interface builder seems to be the only usable version of the few I've used so far.